# Kafka Streams: Cases where "Coordinator selected invalid assignment protocol: null"

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm finding this issue in the logs on a Kafka Streams application (ver 2.1).

```
 Coordinator selected invalid assignment protocol: null
```

The code in Kafka client library seems simple, where an assignor is not found:

```
PartitionAssignor assignor = lookupAssignor(assignmentStrategy);
    if (assignor == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Coordinator selected invalid 
assignment protocol: " + assignmentStrategy);
```

and the lookupAssignor just looks by name:

```
private PartitionAssignor lookupAssignor(String name) {
    for (PartitionAssignor assignor : this.assignors) {
        if (assignor.name().equals(name))
            return assignor;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Under which circumstances this may happen on a Kafka Streams application? What are the consequences?

Comment: Sound like an overlap of different applications. If you have two independent applications, that by accident use the same `group.id`, this could happen. In particular if you have KafkaStreams application and a "plain consumer" using the same group id.

Comment: Not any of those cases though. However some KS tasks were being automatically restarted at the time (via Docker). But even so, what could be causing it in that case?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax we are also experiencing this issue. Have multiple instances of the same applications but they have a prefix in their groupId/topic names. Kafka-streams 2.2, cluster is on 5.1.2. Cluster is under heavy load. Any ideas on what can we look at?

Comment: No other idea atm, beside what I already said about overlapping `group.id`. Maybe check Jira if there is anything and maybe open a bug report?

Comment: Based on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7263 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8104, it seems it is an issue on the consumer side. The fix is in Kafka consumer 2.4